# Pauli matrices computation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Does anyone know how I can find the value of
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{1} K_{i}\left(\frac{\mathbb{I}+\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\sigma}  }{2} \right) K_{i}^{\dagger}
$$
in terms of 
$$
\frac{\mathbb{I}+\vec{r'}\cdot \vec{\sigma} }{2}?
$$
Here $r = (x, y, z)$, $r' = (x', y', z')$,
$$
\sigma_x = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right), \quad
\sigma_y = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -j \\
j & 0
\end{array}\right), \quad
\sigma_z = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right),
$$
with $j = \sqrt{-1}$, and
$$
K_0 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{1-p}
\end{array}\right), \quad
K_1 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \sqrt{p} \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right).
$$

Comment: What is $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r'}$? And what is $p$? Have you tried just plain matrix multiplication and addition?

Comment: @Andrei $\vec{r}={x,y,z}$, $p$ is some probability, and $\vec{r}'$ is a new position vector. Yes I have tried it and more...

Comment: How id $\vec{r'}$ related to $\vec{r}$? You could just use $\vec{r}=\vec{r'}\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r'})$

Comment: @Andrei this is what I want to know. I want to compute $\sum_{i=1}^{i=2}k_{i}\left(\frac{\mathbb{I}+\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\sigma}  }{2} \right) k_{i}^{\dagger}$ using this $K_{1}, K_{2}$ and find the new $\vec{r}'(p)$

Comment: Is $p$ a constant or an operator?

Comment: $p \in \mathbb{R}$. $p \geq 0, p \leq  1$. @Andrei

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from $$\mathbb{I}+\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\sigma}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1+z & x-jy \\
        x+jy & 1-z \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
I used $j=\sqrt{-1}$, as not to confuse with the summation index. Now the problem is just a simple matrix multiplication/addition issue. Your final answer should be (assuming no mistakes on my part):
$$\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
        1+z' & x'-jy' \\
        x'+jy' & 1-z' \\
        \end{pmatrix}= \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
        1+(p+z-pz) & \sqrt{1-p} (x-jy) \\
        \sqrt{1-p} (x+jy) & 1-(p+z-pz) \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
When you identify the terms you get:
$$
x'=\sqrt{1-p} x\\
y'=\sqrt{1-p} y\\
z'=(z-1)(1-p)+1
$$